# How to make Vert.x EventBus.send process requests sequentially?

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-eventbus

I'm new to vert.x and would like to know if its possible to configure eventbus somehow to make it work consistently?

I mean need to send requests one by one using vert.x

At the moment I got this code which uses eventloop principle and waits until all handlers finished, but I don't need this done that fast, idea is to free server from lots of requests at the same time. Here `eb_send()` uses default `EventBus.send()` method. In other words I want to execute all requests with blocking, waiting for answers before requests.

```
List<Future> queue = new ArrayList<>();

files.forEach(fileObj -> {
                Future<JsonObject> trashStatusHandler = Future.future();
                queue.add(trashStatusHandler);


                eb_send(segment, StorageType.getAddress(StorageType.getStorageType(fileInfo.getString("storageType"))) + ".getTrashStatus", fileInfo, reply -> {
                    Entity dummy = createDummySegment();
                    try {
                        if (reply.succeeded()) {
                            //succeded
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        log.error(ex);
                    }
                    trashStatusHandler.complete();
                });
            });
```

Comment: you want to send requests one by one, or wait till they all are finished?

Comment: Probably you mean "sequentially" (one after the other), and not "consistently" (in every case)?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin yes that's right sequentially, sorry

Comment: @injecteer one by one. sequentially =)

Comment: in your code the requests are sequentially sent one by one. What was the problem again?

Comment: @injecteer  yes, but i need to send next request only when previous is done and returned.

Comment: One option out of box would be to use `CompositeFuture.join( filesFutures ).onComplete(..)`, where the `onComplete()` is fired when all futures are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to extract this into a function, which you would invoke recursively.

```java
public void sendFile(List<File> files, AtomicInteger c) {
    eb_send(segment, StorageType.getAddress(StorageType.getStorageType(fileInfo.getString("storageType"))) + ".getTrashStatus", fileInfo, reply -> {
                    Entity dummy = createDummySegment();
                    try {
                        if (reply.succeeded()) {
                            //succeded
                        }
                        // Recursion 
                        if (c.incrementAndGet() < files.size()) {
                            sendFile(files, c);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        log.error(ex);
                    }
                });
}
```